# LCD display under power saving mode

Tags: power, lcd

To make LCD display, Pro Mini and ATMega2560 to run on one set of battery for months, appreciate idea and comment.

Which LCD to use?

Which LCD chip controller chip (hide inside the LCD) has better power saving mode?

Which library with functions of power saving and also can put out **VERY beautiful** per-programmed display, like multiple fonts, different fonts size, some graphics like circle, rectangles, color fills, gradual-color-changing background with text and graphic at 'foreground' (as in PC power point style)?

Under context of

1. Small Mono chrome 2 lines text display
2. 3 inches mono chrome graphic 128 x 64 or similar
3. 3 inches color graphic, 320 x240 or similar

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I think that is impossible. You'd have to look into only turning the lcd on when needed to save power.

Comment: So far no reply, Context 2 and 3 may be impossible, so, I re-do a new question focusing on getting a good Arduino library matching a LCD chip. Will see if conetext 1 will receive can-do reply.

Comment: Use a huge battery, or somehow re-charge the battery (solar?).

Answer (score 1):

Use an eInk/ePaper style display, which uses no power while the display is not changing.  These come in monochrome greyscale, and have excellent readability.

This solves only part of your problem as you still need to power the CPU.

Comment: Agree, eInk can do. However, supply is hard to get than LCD